# Umask for internal-sftp doesn't honor on Centos 7

Tags: ssh, sftp

I've tried setting the following but I'm not getting the desired state of `rw-rw----`.

## Parent folder:

```
drwxrwsr-x  2 clientname airflow 28 Sep 11 15:17 incoming
```

## SSHD config

```
Match group sftpusers
  ForceCommand internal-sftp -u 0002
```

Comment: Are you using a 4.7+ kernel?  Get the pid of the `sftp-server` process when a client is connected.  Then look at the file `grep -i umask /proc/PID/status` and see what that is reporting?  Also what is the `cat //proc/PID/cmdline`?